# The most efficient way to assign several small matrices onto a large matrix in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a big matrix A with shape (10, 10)

```
array([[2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
       [2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

and an array of positions B with shape (5, 2)

```
array([[4, 5], # row 4, column 5
       [2, 1],
       [2, 5],
       [4, 1],
       [6, 7]])
```

and several small matrices C with shape (5, 2, 2)

```
array([[[7, 9],
        [6, 7]],

       [[6, 6],
        [9, 6]],

       [[9, 6],
        [8, 9]],

       [[8, 7],
        [8, 7]],

       [[8, 6],
        [7, 7]]])
```

Now, I want to assign these 5 small matrices to the large matrix. The positions are the position for the up-left corner of the small matrix.  If there exists overlapping area, we can use the last one, maximum or just sum it up. The effect I want looks like

```
A[B] += C
```

A for loop implementation looks like:

```
for i in range(B.shape[0]): 
    A[B[i][0]:B[i][0]+2,B[i][1]:B[i][1]+2] += C[i]
```

The expected result looks like

```
array([[ 2,  1,  2,  1,  1,  4,  3,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  2,  1,  2,  3,  3,  2,  3,  2,  4],
       [ 1,  9,  9,  4,  2, 13, 10,  3,  4,  1],
       [ 1, 12,  7,  3,  3,  9, 13,  2,  1,  2],
       [ 3, 11,  8,  3,  3,  9, 12,  4,  3,  2],
       [ 2, 12,  8,  4,  2,  7,  8,  2,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  2,  3,  1,  4,  3,  9,  8,  3],
       [ 3,  1,  3,  2,  2,  4,  2, 10, 10,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  2,  1,  3,  4,  4,  1,  3],
       [ 3,  1,  3,  2,  4,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1]])
```

Is there a solution without for loop?

Comment: Can you post your expected output as well as your attempt at a solution using a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays:

```
In [58]: A = np.array([[2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2],
    ...:        [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4],
    ...:        [1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1],
    ...:        [1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2],
    ...:        [3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
    ...:        [2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    ...:        [2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    ...:        [3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    ...:        [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3],
    ...:        [3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
In [59]: B=np.array([[4, 5], # row 4, column 5
    ...:        [2, 1],
    ...:        [2, 5],
    ...:        [4, 1],
    ...:        [6, 7]])
In [60]: C=np.array([[[7, 9],
    ...:         [6, 7]],
    ...: 
    ...:        [[6, 6],
    ...:         [9, 6]],
    ...: 
    ...:        [[9, 6],
    ...:         [8, 9]],
    ...: 
    ...:        [[8, 7],
    ...:         [8, 7]],
    ...: 
    ...:        [[8, 6],
    ...:         [7, 7]]])
```

Your iteration, cleaned up a bit:

```
In [72]: for cnt,(i,j) in enumerate(B):
    ...:     A[i:i+2, j:j+2] += C[cnt]
    ...: 
In [73]: A
Out[73]: 
array([[ 2,  1,  2,  1,  1,  4,  3,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  2,  1,  2,  3,  3,  2,  3,  2,  4],
       [ 1,  9,  9,  4,  2, 13, 10,  3,  4,  1],
       [ 1, 12,  7,  3,  3,  9, 13,  2,  1,  2],
       [ 3, 11,  8,  3,  3,  9, 12,  4,  3,  2],
       [ 2, 12,  8,  4,  2,  7,  8,  2,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  2,  3,  1,  4,  3,  9,  8,  3],
       [ 3,  1,  3,  2,  2,  4,  2, 10, 10,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  2,  1,  3,  4,  4,  1,  3],
       [ 3,  1,  3,  2,  4,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1]])
```

And to make the action clearer, lets start with a 0 array:

```
In [76]: A = np.zeros_like(Acopy)
In [77]: for cnt,(i,j) in enumerate(B):
    ...:     A[i:i+2, j:j+2] += C[cnt]
    ...: 
In [78]: A
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 6, 6, 0, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I don't see overlap, so I think we could construct an index array from `B`, that would allow us to:

```
A[B1] += C
```

and if there was a overlap, it would write the last `C` value.

If we don't like that, there is the `np.add.at` `ufunc` that can perform unbuffered addition (or even `np.max.at`).

But it will take some time to work out the required `B1` indices.

### edit

Here's a way of using `+=`.  I'm using `linspace` to construct a multidimensional index, which will be used inplace of the slices.  Getting shapes right took a lot of trial and error and testing (in an interactive session).  As long as the blocks don't overlap this is fast and correct.  But as documented with `np.add.at`, this won't match the iterative approach when there are duplicate indices.

```
In [125]: B1 = B+2
In [126]: I = np.linspace(B,B1,2,endpoint=False).astype(int)
In [127]: A1 =np.zeros_like(Acopy)
In [128]: A1[I[:,:,0][:,None], I[:,:,1]] += C.transpose(1,2,0)
In [129]: np.allclose(A1,A)
Out[129]: True
```

`I` is a (2,5,2) shape array, where the first 2 in the number of "steps"
In [130]: I
Out[130]:
array([[[4, 5],
[2, 1],
[2, 5],
[4, 1],
[6, 7]],

```
       [[5, 6],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 6],
        [5, 2],
        [7, 8]]])
```

And since the `C` subarrays are (2,2), this is the same as: `np.stack([B,B+1])`

The `C` transpose is needed since this indexing of `A1` produces a (2,2,5) array:

```
In [134]: A1[I[:,:,0][:,None], I[:,:,1]]
Out[134]: 
array([[[7, 6, 9, 8, 8],
        [9, 6, 6, 7, 6]],

       [[6, 9, 8, 8, 7],
        [7, 6, 9, 7, 7]]])
In [135]: _.shape
Out[135]: (2, 2, 5)
```

If some blocks overlap, `np.add.at` can be used to sum the overlaps:

```
In [137]: A1 =np.zeros_like(Acopy)
In [138]: np.add.at(A1, (I[:,:,0][:,None], I[:,:,1]), C.transpose(1,2,0))
In [140]: np.allclose(A1,A)
Out[140]: True
```

or for the largest

```
In [143]: np.maximum.at(A1, (I[:,:,0][:,None], I[:,:,1]), C.transpose(1,2,0))
In [144]: np.allclose(A1,A)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple forloop can solve this:

```
import numpy as np

initial = np.array([
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1], [1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2], 
    [3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2], [2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
    [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1],
])

offsets = np.array([[4, 5], [2, 1], [2, 5], [4, 1], [6, 7]])

subarrays = np.array([
    [[7, 9], [6, 7]], [[6, 6], [9, 6]], [[9, 6], [8, 9]], 
    [[8, 7], [8, 7]], [[8, 6], [7, 7]],
])

for subarray, offset in zip(subarrays, offsets):
    (a, b), (c, d) = offset, subarray.shape
    initial[a:a+c, b:b+d] += subarray

print(initial)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that the number of subarrays sometimes gets very large in my situation. And I can sacrifice some sort of accuracy for efficiency in the overlapping area which can be assigned flexibly.

Answer (score 0):

See, what I have tried, without using any kind of loop

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
       [2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
B= np.array([[4, 5], # row 4, column 5
       [2, 1],
       [2, 5],
       [4, 1],
       [6, 7]])

C=np.array([[[7, 9],
        [6, 7]],

       [[6, 6],
        [9, 6]],

       [[9, 6],
        [8, 9]],

       [[8, 7],
        [8, 7]],

       [[8, 6],
        [7, 7]]])

D= np.array([[ 2,  1,  2,  1,  1,  4,  3,  2,  2,  2], # this is required
       [ 3,  2,  1,  2,  3,  3,  2,  3,  2,  4],
       [ 1,  9,  9,  4,  2, 13, 10,  3,  4,  1],
       [ 1, 12,  7,  3,  3,  9, 13,  2,  1,  2],
       [ 3, 11,  8,  3,  3,  9, 12,  4,  3,  2],
       [ 2, 12,  8,  4,  2,  7,  8,  2,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  2,  3,  1,  4,  3,  9,  8,  3],
       [ 3,  1,  3,  2,  2,  4,  2, 10, 10,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  2,  1,  3,  4,  4,  1,  3],
       [ 3,  1,  3,  2,  4,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1]])
```

We need A==D.
I created row and column indexes for all value of C.

```
b_row=np.repeat(np.c_[B[:,0],B[:,0]+1], repeats=2, axis=1).ravel()
b_col=np.repeat(np.c_[B[:,1],B[:,1]+1], repeats=2, axis=0).ravel()
print(np.c_[bx,by])  # to see indexes

A[b_row,b_col]+=C.ravel()
```

Now you can check

```
print(A==D)
False in (A==D)
```